# Raspberry pi keyboard layout is messed up

Tags: raspberry-pi

I changed my pi's keyboard layout to US. After the restart, the keyboard is completely messed up. typing 's' shows 'o' and so on. Long story short, I'm not even able to login. Is there a way to restore the default settings before login? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can log in via SSH, then the keyboard layout of the host doesn't matter. You can then reset the host keyboard layout depending on your installed distribution.

Comment: Ha. I haven't enable ssh in my pi. Since this was a new config I went ahead and re installed raspbian.  Thank you :)

Comment: @skmvasu: Well, good to hear that you have it solved now. You could have also enabled SSH by mounting the partition from the SD card on another machine: http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/4444/enabling-ssh-on-rpi-without-screen-keystrokes-for-raspi-config